# I can't configure my networks or use my wifi adapter

Tags: installation, wireless

I'm dual clienting windows vista and ubuntu 11.10, and i have it set to where i can choose which i use at startup. Now the problem i'm having is that i use and external usb wireless adapter and i can't figure out how to either install the program that runs it or even make ubuntu find it. The adapter works fine in windows but until i figure out how to make it work in ubuntu i can't update or even really use it there. I have crossover saved to the hdd but i truthfully don't know how to make ubuntu install it. And before i forget i'm using a netgear N300 wireless adapter model wna3100. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://opensource.bureau-cornavin.com/belkin/index.html

Translated into your instance, this link can be of substantial help. What needs to be done is that the driver either needs to be loaded from the kernel using modprobe, downloaded and installed (if it's a unix driver), or ndiswrapper'd windows drivers will work if all else fails.

It looks like the main issue is just getting the driver in place, and everything is clear from there.

Comment: that might work, i'm still curious if i have to somehow install the base program. I noticed a little while ago that in windows it constantly cuts on and off without searching for signal unless the program is running in the taskbar.